# Como sumar un campo de mi tabla con cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x, sum

He intentado lo siguiente, no me devuelve ningún error pero no encuentro el resultado de la suma.

```
foreach ($idstareas as $idtarea)
{    
$sumatorio = $this->ProyectosCategoriasTareas->find();
$sumatorio
    ->select(['suma' => $sumatorio->func()->sum('tiempo_acumulado')])
    ->where(['tarea_id'=>$idtarea->id])
    ->toArray();
debug($sumatorio);
die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo he resulto de la siguiente manera

```
foreach ($idstareas as $idtarea)
    {    
    $arrayTareas = $this->ProyectosCategoriasTareas->find('all')->where(['tarea_id'=>$idtarea->id]);
    $collection = new Collection($arrayTareas);
    $sumDeHoras = $collection->sumOf('tiempo_acumulado');
    debug($sumDeHoras);
    die();
    }
```